# HTML: select default option when select tag holds a function

Tags: javascript, html, perl, html-select

What I have is this dropdown:

```
<select>
  [_Perl function that builds and returns options_]
</select>
```

There are only two options, Current and Previous, but the perl code defaults a "Pick One" option.

The perl returns

```
"<OPTION VALUE=\"$item\" SELECTED>$item</OPTION>"
```

where $item is an entry in a dynamically built list.

I have already asked if I can change this over-complicated design, but I am not allowed. I want to throw some JS at it, however, I don't know how to interact with the perl.

Comment: Where to start? Look at the generated HTML.

Comment: It is good to understand: usually, the perl run on the server and the javascript (not counting node.js) runs in the browser. So, what you mean with: _I want to throw some JS at it, however, I don't know how to interact with the perl._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that you can grab the DOM element and set it to, in this case, Current or Previous and it is smart enough not to add another option to your select list. Turns out I didn't have to deal with Perl at all.

Onkeydown in an text element I wanted it to default the select, my JS looks like

```
 function defaultCurrent(<DOMelement.name>) {
     if (<DOMelement.name> == "<specific status as first>") {
         var element = document.querySelector("#<selectElementID>");
         if (element.value == "")
             element.value = "Current";
     }
     else {
         <some not-first logic>
         var element = document.querySelector("#<selectElementID>");
         if (element.value == "")
             element.value = "Previous";
     }
 }
```

where if there is no option selected ("Pick One" = null) then it defaults to the appropriate status.

Moral of the story is, you could do this when you have a traditional

```
<select>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
</select>
```

list too, if it were needed.